# Why this SQL executes in MySQL and not through Eclipse?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have the following table in MYSQL:

```
  CREATE TABLE 't001_prospeccao' (
  'pro_id' bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'pro_cliente' bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  'pro_produto' bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  'pro_status' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  'pro_vlr_entabulado' double DEFAULT NULL,
  'pro_vlr_contratado' double DEFAULT NULL,
  'pro_vlr_utilizado' double DEFAULT NULL,
  'pro_obs' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  'pro_dt_visita' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  'pro_dt_originacao' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  'pro_protocolo' double DEFAULT NULL,
  'pro_correio' double DEFAULT NULL,
  'pro_dt_status' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  'pro_funci' bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('pro_id'),
  UNIQUE KEY 'id_UNIQUE' ('pro_id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And the following INSERT statement, which executes normally in MySQL console:

```
INSERT INTO t001_prospeccao (pro_cliente,pro_produto) VALUES (123456789,111)
```

But, on running this code in Eclipse, an error occours:

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO t001_prospeccao (pro_cliente,pro_produto) VALUES (?,?);";

            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            try {
                stmt.setLong(1, p.getCliente().getMci());
                stmt.setLong(2, p.getProduto().getCod());

                stmt.execute(sql);

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                stmt.close();
            }
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?)' at line 1
```

Data from stmt object:

```
INSERT INTO t001_prospeccao (pro_cliente,pro_produto) VALUES (123456789,111)
```

What should I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not exactly "running in Eclipse". Eclipse has database tools that communicate with SQL databases, that would be "running in Eclipse". This is just Java code (unless there would be different behaviour when executing the code from the IDE and the command line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `Statement.execute(String)` where you should use the `PreparedStatement.execute()` method:

```
stmt.execute(sql);
```

That line should be:

```
stmt.execute();
```